# Alfresco: Content model customization to add custom field during file upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, form-submit, alfresco

I just have started to work with Alfresco repository so I'm very much new to this technology. I'm facing a common problem to file upload(using simple HTML form submit) to add custom data to be saved.

I'm able to upload file to my alfresco repository. I'm also trying to add description, title as a field but they are not saved. When I check from Alfresco data dictionary web interface I find description field is blank.

Also, I need to save custom data like file size, image height, image width, file codec etc. 
I've searched a lot this forum and internet and found several answers but none of them are complete or relevant to my work. In many cases it is stated that I need to define my custom fields in the content model XML but I'm not sure enough how to do that.

I would like to mention some references,

```
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide

http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/05/19/alfresco-tutorial-custom-content-types

http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html
```

Another problem is most of the answers are related to JAVA which is not my technology.

I need to upload file with simple form submit by post data using the file upload API as
/alfresco/service/api/upload.

Along with custom data to be saved.
I'm bound to use technologies like **HTML, Javascript, Jquery**.

If someone help me by stating step-by-step process to achieve this it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: uh... it seems really broad. Could You please split Your problem into separate questions. Also, code sample with what's expected, what have You tried and what's happening --- would help tremendously.

Comment: Hi Kamiccolo, thanks for your interest. I've explained my problem as much I could. If you want a one liner I can say that: "File upload in Alfresco repository along with custom data field using simple HTML form submit or javascript".

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html) on custom content types, which also includes a section on CMIS, which you may find relevant.

Comment: Hi Jeff,

I went through your tutorial and did some task as it states to create custom model xml file.

After that it says that I need to use Maven but I'm not JAVA developer neither my working environment is. I want to use HTML form, javascript and Alfresco file upload API. 
As much I understand,

1. I need to create a model.xml file under model directory(this part is done).
2. Need to specify some association rule with my custom fields, which are mentioned in my model.xml so my custom fields can be saved in alfresco repo(This part is doubtful. I don't figure out how or where I can do that)

Comment: If your model file exists and you have added a reference to it in a context XML file, all that is left to do is to deploy it to your Alfresco WAR. The best way to do this is to use an AMP, and if you use Maven it will handle everything for you. If you cannot or don't want to use Maven, please see http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Packaging_And_Deploying_Extensions to learn how to deploy manually.